# Formatting coordinates from Google Earth georeferencing for projection on QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, geocoding, google-earth

I have XY data from a .csv sheet without any metadata. Presuming WGS84 or UTM CRS, the points won't display correctly on a Google Earth basemap with QGIS when imported as XY data points.

My data was obtained from georeferencing photos using Google Earth (by someone else). The points are all located in the eastern tropical Pacific. For example, this point is supposed to be in Baja Mexico, in the [Gulf of California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_of_California): X = 567013.19217100000, Y = 2686099.92336000000. I have no idea of what settings the person used when they were georeferencing.

None of these standard formats appear to be used: https://www.earthpoint.us/convert.aspx

What is the format of the data, and what transformations do I need to do to project my XY point data onto the map?

Comment: Try EPSG:32612 (WGS 84 / UTM zone 12N) based on inputting your X, Y coords to [profinder](http://projfinder.com/)

Comment: Where exactly is this "Baja Mexico" located? Is it actually ***in*** the Gulf of California?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your coordinates need to be converted.

The example coordinates you provided are not standard latitude/longitudes. Latitudes have a maximum of +/- 90 degrees (at the poles) and longitudes have a maximum of +/- 180 degrees (at the anti-meridian).  Your numbers are in the hundreds of thousands, which makes me wonder if they are in some UTM projection.  You'll need to find out what coordinate system and/or projection they are in and then import them into GIS software that can reproject them to standard WGS84 latitudes/longitude coordinates.